# Hibernate Inheritance Duplicating row when changing superclass object when converting into subclass

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc

I have the following models, Person which is a super class to Patient and Practitioner. Person objects can be instantiated however they can be changed later to either become Practitioner or Patient, however on converting into subclass objects Hibernate creates a new row in the person table. Here is my class representations. I am using a copy constructor on the Person class to instantiate subclass objects with current person object when converting.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person extends BasePerson{

    private Set<MedicalAidCard> medicalAidCards = new HashSet<MedicalAidCard>();

    public Person() {

    }

    public Person(Person person) {
        this.setActive(person.getActive());
        this.setCity(person.getCity());
        this.setCountry(person.getCountry());
        this.setCreatedBy(person.getCreatedBy());
        this.setDateCreated(person.getDateCreated());
        this.setDateModified(person.getDateModified());
        this.setDateOfBirth(person.getDateOfBirth());
        this.setFirstName(person.getFirstName());
        this.setGender(person.getGender());
        this.setId(person.getId());
        this.setLastName(person.getLastName());
        this.setMaritalStatus(person.getMaritalStatus());
        this.setMiddleName(person.getMiddleName());
        this.setModifiedBy(person.getModifiedBy());
        this.setRace(person.getRace());
        this.setTitle(person.getTitle());
        this.setVersion(person.getVersion());
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="card_person", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="person_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="card_id"))
    public Set<MedicalAidCard> getMedicalAidCards() {
        return medicalAidCards;
    }

    public void setMedicalAidCards(Set<MedicalAidCard> medicalAidCards) {
        this.medicalAidCards = medicalAidCards;
    }  

    @Transient
    public Boolean getPatient(){
        return this instanceof PersonPatient;
    }
}
```

Please not that BasePerson is a @MappedSuperClass containing basic person demographic info

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
@Table(name="patient")
public class PersonPatient extends Person{

    private String fileNumber;
    private String oldFileNumber;
    private Date dateRegistered;

    public PersonPatient() {
    }

    public PersonPatient(Person person) {
        super(person);
    }

    @Column(name="file_number",unique=true)
    public String getFileNumber() {
        return fileNumber;
    }

    public void setFileNumber(String fileNumber) {
        this.fileNumber = fileNumber;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="date_registered")
    public Date getDateRegistered() {
        return dateRegistered;
    }

    public void setDateRegistered(Date dateRegistered) {
        this.dateRegistered = dateRegistered;
    }

    @Column(name="old_file_number")
    public String getOldFileNumber() {
        return oldFileNumber;
    }

    public void setOldFileNumber(String oldFileNumber) {
        this.oldFileNumber = oldFileNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.getId().toString();
    }
```

}

By the way I am using SpringData CrudRepository methods to save and Hibernate is my JPA provider. I had thought of deleting current person however I realised it would not work if current person is already representing another subclass.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is impossible. Inheritance is not the appropriate tool, because, in Java like in Hibernate, an object has a type and can not become something else.

You should probably model this using composition rather than inheritance: a user *has a* practitionar role, or a user *has a* patient role.

Comment: Thank you so much I have changed the model and its now working fine